# Position Vector in Relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, vector-fields, general-relativity

In special relativity, the underlying manifold is the vector space $\mathbb R^4$ equipped with the Minkowski metric. The position of a (point) particle located at $p\in\mathbb R^4$ is the point $p$ itself, at least with respect to the standard basis. A reference frame moving with constant speed $v$ is then another basis related to the standard basis by the Lorentz transformation (or the inverse thereof).

In General relativity we have a general manifold equipped with some Lorentzian metric. For a particle at a point $p$ on the manifold, do we define the position vector locally using some tetrad at the tangent space at $p$? And if the particle is moving, do we keep on choosing a tetrad at each point in order to define the position vector or can we define a tetrad field which smoothly varies with the particle so that the position vector is a smooth vector field? If so, is it possible to define the tetrad globally? Or is there another way of dealing with the situation of defining position vectors in GR?

Thank you.

Comment: The notion of a position vector no longer makes sense in GR.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Please elaborate.

Comment: $p$ is not a position but an *event* that has one time coordinate and three space coordinates. As such it depends on a reference frame. In GR this is not different from SR. Over to the standard textbooks who explain all this in their introductory chapters. (You can learn about tetrads much later).

Comment: @KurtG. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#:~:text=A%20position%20in%20spacetime%20is,Spacetime%20is%20thus%20four%20dimensional.) states that a position in spacetime is called an event. Is that not true?

Comment: You wrote that a point particle is located at $p\in\mathbb R^4\,.$ That is nonsense. The event $p=(t,x,y,z)$ describes at time $t$ something that is located at $(x,y,z)\,.$ When WP decides to call this a "position" that is fine with me but regardless how we are calling things we should aim to know what we are talking about.

Comment: @KurtG. Easy there… . To say that a particle is located at $p$, I am merely referring to the point $p$ on the set $\mathbb R^4$ before the point is given coordinates with respect to whichever frame. Obviously, after the frame is chosen, this will be specified by 4 numbers $(t,x,y,z)$ which are by no means unique. There is no “at time $t$” as if time is universal.

Comment: As I said: all coordinates of $p=(t,x,y,z)$ depend on the frame. None of them is universal.

Comment: GR takes place on a Lirentzian manifold, i.e. a manifold equipped with a metric tensor of signature $(3,1)$ (or $(1,3)$ if you prefer). Such a manifold, with few exceptions, does not have structure of a vector space. If you want to understand why, just think of something simpler, like circle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am aware of this fact and have mentioned it. I am asking if there is another way of making sense of position vectors using tangent spaces which are defined at specific points.

Comment: @ThatoTsabone anything in the tangent space would be more akin to a momentum four vector I feel

Comment: Moishe Kohan just told you that the positions (points of the manifold) are not vectors and you are still calling them position vectors. Modern GR is a subfield of modern differental geometry which helped to clarify a lot of things. Morale: in GR the manifold is $\mathbb R^4$ but we do not consider its poins as vectors.

Comment: @KurtG. I was not saying points on a manifold are vectors but was asking the question: since points on a general manifold are not vectors, is there a notion of a position vector using the concept of tangent spaces? I am okay now, however. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Chris That is indeed the case.

Comment: Sorry for being so annoying. When I do `ctrl+f` I find seven instances of you calling a point on a manifold "position vector". There are plenty of better ways to call those things.

Comment: @KurtG. Its okay. I mention "position vector" seven times (yes) but never identify it as a point on a manifold. Rather, I ask about the position vector of a particle at a point $p$ as possibly being an element of the tangent space at $p$. To add to the fun; the manifold in GR is not $\mathbb R^4$ as you claim but is **_locally_** $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: no, the concept of position vector field is pretty meaningless on a general manifold. Locally, you can always transport data using a chart, but you won’t be able to globally piece it together (more abstractly: *you can’t put humpty-dumpty back together*). You mention tangent spaces, so let me just remark that on the tangent bundle, we have the identity map $I:TM\to TM$. Classically, this map would be denoted by a symbol like $dP$ or $d\mathbf{r}$, and referred to as an *infinitesimal displacement vector*, even though there is no such thing as $P$ or $\mathbf{r}$ by itself.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks. This is very helpful.

Comment: If your manifold is itself a finite dimensional real vector space $V$, then the tangent spaces at each point in the manifold will each be naturally isomorphic to $V$. In this situation, we can identify the tangent space at $p \in V$ with $V$ itself. Thus all points in the space and all tangent vectors are elements of $V$. To differentiate between the points in the space and the tangent vectors, we call the points "position vectors". That is all "position vector" means: a vector of $V$ that we are treating as a point of the manifold, rather than as a tangent vector to the manifold.